# Как найти NPM пакет который делает запросы на стороние сайты?

Tags: vue.js, api, npm

Есть проект на VueJS, в нём куча строронних плагинов NPM. Подключил Application Insights и он показывает, что с сайта делаются запросы на сторонние сайты.

Как понять кто делает эти запросы, точнее, что делает запросы?

Скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. поиск по коду ничего не дал, потому что нечестные люди сделали обфускацию? тогда попробуйте поискать функции которые любят обфускаторы 2. npm audit делали? 3. в консоле браузера можно найти запросы? тогда вкладка Сеть > initiator покажет с какого места был запуск запроса

Comment: 4. если проект под гитом, можно через `git bisect` найти коммит в котором начала проявляться пробема => узнать какой пакет ставился. `с сайта делаются запросы на сторонние сайты` - запросы из браузера летят из с сервера?